# How to read CSV file (all numerical) as a matrix directly?

Tags: r

I have a very big csv file. I read it in memory as df. However, when I try to convert it into a matrix. df = data.matrix(df), R is out of memory.

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.3 Gb

Are there a way that csv file can be read directly as a matrix without going through the df intermediate step?

Comment: perhaps you could start a fresh session and try loading the object first thing, wrapping your file import in a `as.matrix()`

Comment: you might try `matrix(scan("myfile.csv",sep=","),ncol=...)`

Comment: these sites might help: http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-large-tables.html and http://cbio.ensmp.fr/%7Ethocking/reading-large-text-files-into-R.html